# Remainder form of Taylor polynomial at $x_0$: $ \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0 +\theta(x-x_0))(x-x_0)^n$ with $\theta \to \frac{1}{n+1}$ as $ x \to x_0$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

If the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is $n+1$ times differentiable at $x_0$ and $f^{(n+1)}(x_0) \neq 0$, then a form of the remainder in Taylor's Formula is supposedly

$$r_n(x_0;x) = \frac{f^{(n)}\big(x_0 +\theta(x-x_0)\big)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n,$$ where $ 0< \theta < 1$ and $\theta = \theta(x)$ approaches $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as $x$ approaches $x_0.$

How would one derive this?

This seems quite strange to me.

For example, taking $f(x) =e^x$, the normal Taylor expansion for $n=2$ at $0$ would have the form 
(Lagrange Remainder): $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac12x^2 +\frac{1}{3!}e^{\xi}x^3,$$ but in this case it is

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac12x^2 +\frac{1}{2!}e^{\theta(x)}x^2$$.

The properties of $\theta$ do not make much sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you give a reference for the expression of your remainder?

Comment: @MusséRedi Mathematical Analysis I by Vladimir Zorich; page 233, exercise 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Taylor-Lagrange formula we have, for $x$ in the neighborhood of $x_0$:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+\theta_x(x-x_0))}{n!}(x-x_0)^n\tag{1}
$$
with $\theta_x\in(0,1)$, and we are interested in $\lim_{x\to x_0}\theta_x$.
Taking one step further in Taylor-Lagrange formula we have also
$$\eqalign{
f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k\cr&\phantom{=}+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}\tag{2}}
$$
with $\phi_x\in(0,1)$.
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+\theta_x(x-x_0))}{n!} =\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} +\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)
$$
or
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+\theta_x(x-x_0))-f^{(n)}(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))}{ n+1 }
$$
that is
$$
\theta_x=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))}{ \dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0+h_x)-f^{(n)}(x_0)}{h_x} }
$$
where $h_x=\theta_x(x-x_0)$. Letting $x$ tend to $x_0$ and noting that $f^{(n+1)}(x_0)\ne0$, we get
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \theta_x=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
which is the desired conclusion.$\qquad\square$

Comment: Was the notation incorrect in the question? Specifically, should it have been called $r_{n-1}(x_0;x)$ to remain consistent?

Comment: @user149129 It is a matter of convention. Because you recall the expression that you denote by $r_n(x_0;x)$ in the statement of your question.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand what you mean. I am referring to the fact that ordinarily $r_n(x_0;x)$ denoted the remainder that was after the term containing $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: generally, I would call $r_n(x_0;x)$ what remains after taking away $n$ terms (corresponding to $k=0,\ldots,n-1$) of the Taylor series expansion. So, it is what comes after the term with $f^{(n-1)}(x_0)$, and this is consistent with your notation.

Comment: Oh, right. I am asking this because the source of the question had the convention of my previous comment, which is why I was confused and gave the nonsensical second example.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Could you please give more details how you obtained that $\theta_x$ tends to $\frac{1}{n+1}$? Where did you use that $f^{(n+1)}(x_0)\neq 0$? Would be thankful for your help!

Comment: @ZFR Note that (i) $ \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+\theta_x(x-x_0))-f^{(n)}(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \theta_x\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0+\theta_x(x-x_0))-f^{(n)}(x_0)}{\theta_x(x-x_0)}$ and (ii) $\dfrac{f^{(n)}(x_0+h_x)-f^{(n)}(x_0)}{h_x} \to f^{(n+1)}(x_0) $.

Comment: @copper.hat, the last limit is valid because when $x\to x_0$ then $h_x\to 0$ right? Since $h_x=\theta(x-x_0)$ and $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @ZFR That is correct.

Comment: @copper.hat, That Is true. But there is also one moment which bothers me: the author claims that $f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))\to f^{(n+1)}(x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$, right? But it may not be true since $f^{(n+1)}$ may not be continuous.

Comment: @ZFR I thought $f$ was assumed $n+1$ times differentiable at $x_0$?

Comment: @copper.hat, yes it is $n+1$ times differentiable. But it does imply that $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous right? Because $\lim \limits_{x\to x_0} f^{(n+1)}(x_0+\phi_x(x-x_0))\to f^{(n+1)}(x_0)$ holds if $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous at $x_0$. Am I right?

Comment: @ZFR I see your point.

Comment: @copper.hat, So probably the function $f$ should be from the class $C^{(n+1)}$ and if not then some other solution should be for this case.

Comment: @ZFR I suspect the result is correct but the above proof needs some work.

Comment: @copper.hat, So you mean the conclusion is still true if $f^{(n+1)}$ not continuous?

Comment: @ZFR I think there are may assumptions missing in the question. Most forms of Taylor's theorem that I am comfortable with require something like $f^{(n)}$ to be continuous in an interval containing $x_0$ in its interior. I am taking a quick look at Zorich, but there are many places where there are leaps made that I am uncomfortable with (remarks in Lemma 2 in Section 5.3.3 for example). Unfortunately I do not have the time at present to investigate further. I suspect Theorem 2 in Section 5.3.3 might be relevant for appropriate choice of $\phi$.

Comment: @ZFR I suspect that implicit in Zorich's question is that $f^{(n)}$ is defined on some interval around $x_0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, the proof above is not consistent since it uses continuity of $f^{(n+1)}$ at $x_0$.

Comment: @ZFR The above proof is not valid. However, I think more hypotheses are needed (such as $f^{(n)}$ being valid in an interval containing $x_0$).

Comment: @copper.hat, but I guess that this is already given since we are given Theorem 2. And it states that functiin $f$ has first $n$ continuous derivatives in closed interval $[x_0,x]$ and has $(n+1)$ derivative in the interior of this interval, i.e. $(x_0,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the following I have a slightly different notation of the Lagrange form of the remainder than  the OP's. If the OP insists on his notation please comment.

Let the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $k+1$ times differentiable at $x_0$. Denote its $k$-th order Taylor polynomial by $P_k(t)$ and define the function $F(t)$ by $$F(t) = f(t) + f'(t)(x-t)+\frac{f''(t)}{2!}(x-t)^2 + \ldots + \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!}(x-t)^k.
$$
We show a way to arrive at the Lagrange- and Cauchy remainder forms.

Note that our remainder term is given by
\begin{align*} R_k(x) =& f(x) - P_k(x) \\ =& F(x) - F(x_0) . \end{align*}

Let $G$ be any real-valued function, continuous on the closed interval $[x_0,x]$ and differentiable with a non-vanishing derivate on the open interval $(x_0,x)$.

By Cauchy's mean value theorem we then have 
$$\frac{F'(\xi)}{G'(\xi)} = \frac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{G(x)-G(x_0)}, \quad (*)
$$
for some $\xi \in (x_0,x)$.

Now consider the derivative of $F(t)$,
\begin{align*} 
F'(t) =& f'(t) + \big(f^{(2)}(t)(x-t) - f'(t)\big) + \Bigg(\frac{f^{(3)}(t)}{2!}(x-t)^2-\frac{f^{(2)}}{1!}(x-t)\Bigg) + \ldots +  \Bigg( \frac{f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k-\frac{f^{(k)}(t)}{(k-1)!}(x-t)^{k-1}\Bigg) \\
=& \frac{f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k.
\end{align*}

Plugging this into $(*)$ and rearranging terms we find an expession for the remainder
$$ R_k(x) = F'(\xi)\frac{G(x)-G(x_0)}{G'(x)}.
$$
Choosing $G(t) = (x-t)^{k+1}$ yields the Lagrange form of the remainder
$$ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{k+1}(\xi)}{(k+1)!}(x-x_0)^k.
$$
Choosing $G(t) = t-a$ yields the Cauchy form of the remainder
$$ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{k+1}(\xi)}{k!}(x-\xi)^k (x-x_0).
$$

**PS**: The last step of choosing $G(t)$ seems a bit obscure to me, although it works out obviously. Maybe someone can elaborate on what choices of $G(t)$ are valid?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, sorry. I understand/ have seen the derivation of the Lagrange and Cauchy form of the remainder. What I do not understand is the remainder form in the title. I will edit the post.